# Alter existing model with a Redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, redmine

The Redmine plugin tutorials explain how to wrap core models but what I need is to add another column to the journals table. 
I need a boolean field inserted in the journals model. Creating another model with a 'belongs_to :journal' relation seems like an overkill.
Can this be done with a plugin?
I should note that I am a rails newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to create the appropriate [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

In your plugin's directory, create the file `db/migrate/update_journal.rb` with the following :

```
class UpdateJournal < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        change_table :journal do |t|
            t.column :my_bool, :boolean
        end
    end

    def self.down
        change_table :journal do |t|
            t.remove :my_bool
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can execute the task `rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production` to update your database with the new field.

After executing the migration, your journal database will have the `my_bool` field that you'll be able to call like every other field.

Comment: This way seem does not work any more. Do you have any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extend the existing user model using the following code:

```
class UpdateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :your_new_column, :string, :default => ''
    add_column :users, :your_other_new_column, :string, :default => ''
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :your_new_column
    remove_column :users, :your_other_new_column
  end
end
```

Also I needed to name the migration file in way that it began with a number eg. myplugin/db/migrate/001_update_user.rb